# Predicate Logic Question: Implications/Operations on the Empty Set

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Suppose T is a set of Natural numbers.

C1: $2$ is the only prime number that divides elements of $T$

C2: $T$ is the set of all natural numbers that satisfy the quadratic equation $x^2+x+1=0$.

I'm trying to find out if C1 $\Rightarrow$ C2, and the other way around.

I know that C2 is the empty set, so I'm guessing C2 $\Rightarrow$ C1 because it's vacuously true?

Please help. Cheers.

Comment: $C_2$ is not the empty set, it is a formula. And the sentence $\forall T(C_2\to C_1)$ is false. It is not clear what $C_1$ actually means. That $2$ is the only prime that divides *every* element of $T$? That is the interpretation I made. Or is it some element of $T$?

Comment: How is $C_2$ not empty? Can you think of a natural number that satisfies the equation?

Comment: Of course the set $T$ described there is empty. But $\to$ is a sentential connective.  I took your question to ask whether $\forall T(C_2\to C_1)$ is true. (You used $\implies$, same thing.) What makes the sentence false is that there are other primes that divide every element of $T$.

Comment: Okay so if T is an empty set, does $C1 \Rightarrow C2$? I'm just having issues understanding how 2 can divide the 'non-elements' of the empty set T.

Comment: $\forall T(C_1\implies C_2)$ is false. For $T$ could be $\{2,4\}$. But I am a little worried about the whole problem, if it was exactly as stated, for someone who knows logic would noot be so imprecise.

Comment: It is exactly as stated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$% Predefined Typography
 \newcommand{\paren} [1]{\left({#1}\right)}
 \newcommand{\bparen}[1]{\bigg({#1}\bigg)}
 \newcommand{\brace} [1]{\left\{{#1}\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bbrace}[1]{\bigg\{{#1}\bigg\}}
 \newcommand{\floor} [1]{\left\lfloor{#1}\right\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\bfloor}[1]{\bigg\lfloor{#1}\bigg\rfloor}
 \newcommand{\mag}  [1]{\left\lVert{#1}\right\rVert}
 \newcommand{\bmag} [1]{\bigg\Vert{#1}\bigg\Vert}
 \newcommand{\abs}  [1]{\left\vert{#1}\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\babs} [1]{\bigg\vert{#1}\bigg\vert}
 %
 \newcommand{\labelt}[2]{\underbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\label} [2]{\underbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 \newcommand{\ulabelt}[2]{\overbrace{#1}_{\text{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\ulabel} [2]{\overbrace{#1}_{#2}}
 %
 \newcommand{\setcomp}[2]{\left\{~{#1}~~\middle \vert~~ {#2}~\right\}}
 \newcommand{\bsetcomp}[2]{\bigg\{~{#1}~~\bigg \vert~~ {#2}~\bigg\}}
 %
 \newcommand{\iint}[2]{\int {#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\dint}[4]{\int_{#3}^{#4}{#1}~{\rm d}{#2}}
 \newcommand{\pred}[2]{\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}{#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\ind} [2]{\frac{{\rm d} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predp}[2]{\frac{\partial}{\partial {#2}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indp} [2]{\frac{{\partial} {#1}}{\partial {#2}}}
 \newcommand{\predn}[3]{\frac{\rm d}^{#3}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}#1}
 \newcommand{\indn} [3]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#3} {#1}}{{\rm d}{#2}^{#3}}}
 %
 \newcommand{\ii}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\ee}{{\rm e}}
 \newcommand{\exp}[1] { {\rm e}^{\large{#1}} }
 %
 \newcommand{\and} {~\text{and}~}
 \newcommand{\or} {~\text{or}~}
 %
 \newcommand{\red}  [1]{\color{red}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\blue} [1]{\color{blue}{#1}}
 \newcommand{\green}[1]{\color{green}{#1}}
$
Writing the statements symbolically:

$$\forall (s, p) ~:~ (s \in T \and p \in \text{Primes} \and p\mid s) \rightarrow 2 = p \tag{C1}$$

$$T = \setcomp{x}{x \in \mathbb N \text{ and } x^2 + x + 1 = 0} \tag{C2}$$

From **(C2)**, we know that $T$ is the empty set.  So **(C1)** is:

$$\forall (s, p) ~:~ (s \in \emptyset \and p \in \text{Primes} \and p\mid s) \rightarrow 2 = p$$

$$\forall (s, p) ~:~ (\text{false} \and p \in \text{Primes} \and p\mid s) \rightarrow 2 = p$$

$$\forall (s, p) ~:~ \text{false} \rightarrow 2 = p$$

$$\forall (s, p) ~:~ \text{true}$$

$$\text{true}$$

So **(C2)** implies **(C1)**.

On the other hand, if we assume **(C1)** (assuming T is a subset of the natural numbers so that divisibility is defined):

$$\forall (s, p) ~:~ (s \in T \and p \in \text{Primes} \and p\mid s) \rightarrow 2 = p$$
$$T \subseteq \{1,~ 2,~ 4,~ 8,~ 16,~ 32,~ \dots\}$$

Does $T \subseteq \{1,~ 2,~ 4,~ 8,~ 16,~ 32,~ \dots\}$ imply that $T = \emptyset$?  Sometimes yes, sometimes no.  For example:

$$\begin{array} {c|c|c} \hline
\text{Value of T} & T \subseteq \{1,~ 2,~ 4,~ 8,~ 16,~ 32,~ \dots\} \rightarrow T = \emptyset & \text{..which is:} \\
\hline
T = \{3\} & \text{false} \rightarrow \text{false} & \text{true} \\
T = \{4, 8\} & \text{true} \rightarrow \text{false} & \text{false} \\
T = \{\} & \text{true} \rightarrow \text{true} & \text{true} \\
\end{array}$$

So $(C1) \rightarrow (C2)$ is not fully defined.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. When you say, (p∣s), what does that mean?

Comment: @Romaion p divides s, which also means s is divisible by p.

Comment: oh okay, I thought that might be it. thanks again.